# SQL select with with multiple rows for one ID

Tags: mysql, sql, select, pivot, entity-attribute-value

I have two tables:

Table 1: 'user_fields'

```
id  name
1   age
2   birthdate
3   firstname
```

Table 2: 'user_data'

```
user_id user_field_id value
22          1           50
22          2           01.01.1990
22          3           Peter
25          1           33
25          2           05.08.1970
25          3           Steve
```

Now I would like to create a sql statement which shows firstname and birthday for each user_id

example rows:

```
22    Peter    01.01.1990
25    Steve    05.08.1970
```

How should the select look like?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to join the tables (if you don't want to hardcode the values), and then perform an aggregation:

```
SELECT  ud.user_id,
        MIN(CASE WHEN uf.name = 'firstname' THEN ud.value END) as firstname,
        MIN(CASE WHEN uf.name = 'birthday' THEN ud.value END) as birthday
FROM user_data ud
INNER JOIN user_fields uf
    ON ud.user_field_id = uf.user_field_id 
GROUP BY ud.user_id;
```

Ok, per your new requirement, a simple `JOIN` will do:

```
SELECT  ud.user_id,
        MIN(CASE WHEN uf.name = 'firstname' THEN ud.value END) as firstname,
        MIN(CASE WHEN uf.name = 'birthday' THEN ud.value END) as birthday,
        MIN(ac.status) as status
FROM user_data ud
INNER JOIN user_fields uf
    ON ud.user_field_id = uf.user_field_id 
LEFT JOIN api_calls ac
    ON ud.user_id = ac.user_id
GROUP BY ud.user_id;
```

Comment: Now i have a third table, wich I would like to add to my output. 'api_calls' with the collum user_id and status. I would like to add the 'status' for each user_id to the output of the first statement.

Comment: @FabianTschullik what does that mean?, do you want a kind of generic query that would work with that?, because I can't know what do you really want

Comment: @FabianTschullik sorry, too little information. Does the `api_calls` table have only one row per user_id?, what happens if there's more than one?, which status should I choose?. Are there gonna be more tables that you are gonna join later?

Comment: @Lamek: Its only one row per user_id. And there will be one more table with the same syle i would like to join later. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can try joining the table onto itself and filtering on just joining the name with the birthdate:

```
SELECT name.user_id, name.value AS Name, bday.value AS birthdate
FROM t name
INNER JOIN t bday
ON name.user_id = bday.user_id
AND name.t = 3 AND bday.t = 2
```